# How to handle events using drizzle?

Tags: events, logs, drizzle

strange that after much searching, i havent found even one piece of info out there which clearly elaborates on how the events are manipulated in drizzle. From what i understand, the event names (and options) are specified in the Drizzle Options object. But the event array that is received in the drizzleState is a collection of logs from all events. How can we properly filter only certain event types, collected starting from block 0 to 'latest', and select only logevents that satisfy custom conditions pertaining to log values, and inject them into components? any example code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [code snippet](https://github.com/Muhammad-Altabba/ens-angular-truffle-drizzle/blob/fcea37aac06806def699efba6d9d440a447dd827/src/app/util/drizzle.service.ts#L83):

```
export class DrizzleService {
drizzle: Drizzle;
...

constructor(private web3Service: Web3Service) {
    this.init();
}

async init() {

    const options = {
      contracts: [], // Without providing an empty array, an error will be raised
    }

    this.drizzle = new Drizzle(options);
    ...
}
...
async getPastEvents(contractName: string, event: string = 'allEvents', options: any) 
{
    await this.ensureDrizzleInitialization();

    const web3 = this.drizzle.web3;
    const contract = this.drizzle.contracts[contractName];
    const yourContractWeb3 = new web3.eth.Contract(contract.abi, contract.address);
    return await yourContractWeb3.getPastEvents(event, options);
}
```

Full code at: https://github.com/Muhammad-Altabba/ens-angular-truffle-drizzle/

Try it at: https://muhammad-altabba.github.io/ens-angular-truffle-drizzle/

Comment: This is not really answering the question: you show how to handle event using web3, but not how to do this using Drizzle